# C++ routine returning function

Tags: c++11

I have the following code which work fine. I am trying to understand the syntax. The return statement has `std::plus<double>()`. The double over here has the return value data type. But the function definition has the return type as `std::function<double(double, double)>` which indicates two double parameters. How do these two relate to each other?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

std::function<double(double, double)> GetFunction()
{
   return std::plus<double>();
}

int main()
{
   auto operation = GetFunction();

   int a = operation(1, 4);

   std::cout << std::plus<>{}(1, 4) << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an implicit conversion from `std::plus<double>` to `std::function<double(double,double)>`, because the former has a member call operator `double operator()(double, double)`. See the documentation for [std::function constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function).

Answer (score 2):

In `std::function<double(double, double)>`:

The first `double` is the return type of the function. You can remember that by realizing that it's on the left, just like in a normal function definition.

The `double`s in parentheses are the parameter types of the function, just like in a normal function definition; minus the parameter names. There are 2 since the plus function takes 2 `double`s.

This makes sense if you think about it. The plus function/operator is a binary operator, meaning it takes 2 parameters of a type, and returns a single value of the same type. This is why you only need to specify a single type when you write `std::plus<double>`; the parameters and the return type **must** be the same type. It would be error prone and useless to force the caller to specify the same type 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is, why there is only one `double` in the template parameter of `std::plus` but three in `std::function`, then the answer is this:

For `std::plus`, both parameters and the returntype always have to be the same, so you only have to specify it once.
`std::function` on the other hand can hold any function like object with any combination of parameters and returntypes, so you have to basically state each of those types individually.